# .bind(this) sometimes not working on slow device

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I've encountered an issue that sometimes on slower devices the application crashes due to bind(this) does not bind context to class method. For example :

```
class mycomp extends Component {


    render() {
        return <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPress.bind(this)}/>;
    }

    _onPress() {
        let {submit} = this.props; // <-- here throws error 
        submit();
    }

}
```

It says `undefined is not an object {evaluating this.props.submit}` , this only happens on some devices. Have also tried [autobind](https://github.com/andreypopp/autobind-decorator) and the error still happens. The only solution I've found so far is move bind(this) to constructor :

```
class mycomp extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // move `bind` statement here
        this._onPress = this._onPress.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPress}/>;
    }

    _onPress() {
        let {submit} = this.props; 
        submit();
    }

}
```

Or simply inline the function will avoid this error, but I'm still confusing about why this is going to happen, any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you should never use `.bind` in `render` method - it indeed decreases performance.

Instead, use class properties (method are defined with arrow function) to bind context.

```
class Mycomp extends Component {
    _onPress = () => {
        let {submit} = this.props; // <-- here throws error 
        submit();
    }

    render() {
        return <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPress}/>;
    }

}
```

In your case, you can use `onPress={this.props.submit}`, since your `_onPress` method does nothing at all...